# Arduino over a Network

Tags: ethernet

I am new to arduino programming. I want to sense temperature and send it to a server in my college. I am using Arduino Uno R3 board which has ATmega 328P micro-controller. I am able to get serial output on my PC but is there a way in which I can send temperature data to the server in a packet format using Arduino Programmer and not using Ethernet Shield ? Please answer in a less complex way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an ethernet shield or some kind of other internet connectivity shield/circuitry you cannot communicate directly with the internet through the arduino. However, if having a computer as the internet communicator isn't a problem you could try a setup like:

arduino->serial (usb)->[processing](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing)->[internet](http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/how-to-access-internet-through-processing-application.html)

This way you create the internet packet in processing using the temperature information received through serial from arduino.

see also https://processing.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Arduino Yún](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun): it's a Leonardo coupled with a CPU running GNU/Linux (a flavour of OpenWRT).

Using the Bridge library, your sketch can delegate tasks to the linux side.

HttpClient example (Examples > Bridge > HttpClient) GETs a page from the Arduino web site, but the HttpClient class may POST whatever data to a server of choice.

There is also a nice example called [SendDataToGoogleSpreadsheet](https://www.temboo.com/arduino/yun/update-google-spreadsheet) (Examples > Bridge > Temboo > SendDataToGoogleSpreadsheet): it accumulates sensor readings on a google spreadsheet. I've used something like that on a [project of mine](https://github.com/ffissore/badger).